# Editing the base allitems.aspx for surveys in 2010

Tags: list-view, survey, customization, default

We're trying to modify the allitems.aspx base file of the SHP 2010 surveys.

We've find the way, once the survey is created, to create a new view and make that view as default view... but we want to automate the process and, when we create a new survey, the default allitems.aspx list view must be the customized one.

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom solution in Visual Studio might be a good option for you.

You could create an event receiver listening for web/list creation (depending how you create your surveys). 
Receiver could programatticaly add desired view to survey list and make it default one.

Here is post about creating and changing views: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sowmyancs/2008/03/14/programmatically-create-a-view-custom-view-of-a-list-and-change-the-view/

And here is Microsoft how to about creating receivers: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/gg252010(v%3Doffice.14)

Comment: We've been trying the way you propose but with no success. Many thank's for your reply.